# @ORM\ManyToOne (Doctrine trying to fill object instead of int value into column)

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I'm working on a form using a `@ORM\ManyToOne` association, but Doctrine keeps trying to parse the Airport Entity instead of the id of the Airport Entity, I've tried several annotations like `@ORM\JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="id")` but I can't find the right annotation to make doctrine parse just the id of the entity instead of the entity object, any help would be appreciated. Also I'm not seeking a quick and dirty fix, I'm seeking a clean and correct way to do this using the Doctrine annotations if possible.

Full Error Message:

```
An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO flight (from, to) VALUES (?, ?)' with params [{}, {}]:

Notice: Object of class App\Entity\Airport could not be converted to int
```

Flight.php

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\FlightRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="flight",
 *      uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="flight",columns={"from","to"})}
 * )
 */
class Flight
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Airport", inversedBy="outbound")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id")
     */
    private $from;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Airport", inversedBy="inbound")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id")
     */
    private $to;

    public function __toString()
    {
      return $this->name;
    }
```

Airport.php

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\AirportRepository")
 */
class Airport
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=200)
     */
    private $region;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Flight", mappedBy="to")
     */
    private $inbound;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Flight", mappedBy="from")
     */
    private $outbound;
```

Comment: What **definitely** is wrong is your Flight `from` and `to` annotations. because the join column names cannot be "id". also, the the inbound/outbound fields can't be columns (!) and don't need a join column.

Comment: I've made the changes you suggested removed `@ORM\Colum` from the Airport inbound and outbound fields. Also I removed the `@ORM\JoinColumn` from both entity fields, but the exact same error still remains. I have updated the page to reflect my current changes, so they are visible to you

Comment: oh, also remove the Column definitions from the ManyToOnes, they are copied over from the referenced Column. or to be more precise: implied. Column+ManyToOnes will clash

Comment: When I remove `@ORM\Column` from the **'from'** and **'to'** fields on the Flight Entity and run a `php bin/console doctrine:migrations:diff`. I get `There is no column with name 'from' on table 'flight'`. Doctrine doesn't seem to like that.

Comment: in that case, you actually have to add in the `@ORM\JoinColumn(name="from")` (or "to" respectively)

Comment: yes, but the same issue remains the entity object is still not converted to int?

Comment: I believe, something in there acts as if the airport, that is bound to a field, should *also* be an int, which shouldn't happen if you remove the Column annotation on your relation fields. could you update your code again?

Comment: The code is up to date

Comment: in that case you misread. not @ORM\Column, but @ORM\JoinColumn, and remove the type. it's inferred.

Comment: I tried `@ORM\JoinColumn(name="from")` and `@ORM\JoinColumn(name="to")` but undid it. because it didnt fix the issue. But i'll add it again now and update the code

Comment: the Flight.from needs to have the JoinColumn and no Column, and same for the to, the Airport needs no JoinColumn.

Comment: The script is updated but I get again `There is no column with name 'from' on table 'flight'.` when I run `php bin/console doctrine:migrations:diff`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210961/discussion-between-jakumi-and-userx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out that the issue was on the `@ORM\ManyToOne()` side, by chatting with Jakumi:

And that `@ORM\JoinColumn()` converts the entity to a int.
He also pointed out `from` is a reserved keyword in MySQL so I changed the column name to `ap_from`.

Flight.php

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\FlightRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="flight",
 *      uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="flight",columns={"ap_from","ap_to"})}
 * )
 */
class Flight
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Airport", inversedBy="outbound")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="ap_from", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $from;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Airport", inversedBy="inbound")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="ap_to", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $to;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text")
     */
    private $kfm;
```

Answer (score 0):

i don't see any use of putting the oneToMany annotation in the airport class or even the attributes inbounf and outbound just keep the from and to in your flight class then you access to any attribute in the airport throw your flight entity 
your code should look like that :

Flight.php:

```
class Flight{/**
 * @ORM\Id()
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Airport")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="airportFrom" , referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $from;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Airport")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="airportTo", referencedCol)
 */
private $to;
```

Airport.php

```
class Airport{

/**
 * @ORM\Id()
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 */
private $name;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=200)
 */
private $region;
```

and if you are worried about how to get the flights coming in or out from an airport a simple sql query should do it